# How to delete photos from MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, storage, macos, space

I have a MacBook Air and run out of space so want to remove all my photos.

I have deleted all of them by going into photo and also searching for jpg but it still says I have 32 GB of photos but I can't find them anywhere.

I have deleted my trash - any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The bar chart that shows the occupied space the size of all images on your hard drive combined.

If you want to delete your "Photos Library" that's used by the Photos.app do this:

1. Open Finder
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Enter `~/Pictures`
4. Find the "Photos Library" file, select and delete it
5. Empty your trash

Please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Photos.app, go to File > Show Recently Deleted. If there's items there, they didn't erase from your hard drive. If you're sure you don't want any of those, delete them from there.